# cert manager is failing with Waiting for dns-01 challenge propagation: Could not determine authoritative nameservers

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager, azure-dns

I have created cert-manager on aks-engine using below command 
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.12.0/cert-manager.yaml

my certificate spec

[image]

issuer spec

[image]

Im using nginx as ingress, I could see txt record in the azure dns zone created my azuredns service principle, but not sure what is the issue on nameservers

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: I found the cause for it, it is because of  the default name server when installed cert-manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same error... I suspect that it's because I'm using a mix of private and public Azure DNS entries and the record needs to get added to the public entry so letsencrypt can see it, however, cert-manager performs a check that the TXT record is visible before asking letsencrypt to perform the validation... I **assume** that the default DNS records cert-manager looks at is the private one, and because there's no TXT record there, it gets stuck on this error.

The way around it, as described on [cert-manager.io](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/#setting-nameservers-for-dns01-self-check) is to override the default DNS using extraArgs (I'm doing this with terraform and helm):

```
resource "helm_release" "cert_manager" {
  name       = "cert-manager"
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  
  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
  
  set {
    name  = "extraArgs"
    value = "{--dns01-recursive-nameservers-only,--dns01-recursive-nameservers=8.8.8.8:53\\,1.1.1.1:53}"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using helm direct, you can set the extraArgs like that:
`--set extraArgs='{--dns01-recursive-nameservers-only,--dns01-self-check-nameservers=8.8.8.8:53\,1.1.1.1:53}'`

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me, was that I was missing some annotations in the ingress:

```
cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: hydrantid
kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
```

In my case I am using `hydrantid` as the issuer, but most people use `letsencrypt` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when my certificate was stuck in pending and below is how i resolved it

```
kubectl get challenges 
urChallengeName
```

then run the following

```
kubectl patch challenge/urChallengeName -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
```

and when u do get challenges again it should be gone